# How to find number of occurrences of a subset of elements in a vector without using loops in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, frequency

Say X is the given vector:

```
   X=[1
      2
      4
      2
      3
      1
      4
      5
      2
      4
      5];
```

And Y is the given subset of elements from X:

```
Y=[3
   4
   5];
```

The required output is the number of times the elements in Y occur in X:

```
out=[1
     3
     2];
```

My solution to do this would be to use `for` loop:

```
for i=1:size(X,1)
    temp = X(X(:,1)==Y(i,1),:);
    out(i,1) = size(temp,1);
end
```

But when X and Y are large, this is inefficient. So, how to do it faster making use of vectorization? I know about `hist` and `histc`, but I can't think of how to use them in this case to get the desired output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## A Fast Option

You could use `bsxfun` combined with `sum` to compute this

```
sum(bsxfun(@eq, Y, X.'), 2)
```

**Explanation**

In this example, `bsxfun` performs a given operation on every combination of elements in `X` and `Y`. The operation we're gonig to use is `eq` (a check for equality). The result is a matrix that has a row for each element in `Y` and a column for each element in `X`. It will have a `1` value if the element in `X` equals the element in `Y` that corresponds to a given row.

```
bsxfun(@eq, Y, X.')

%    0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
%    0     0     1     0     0     0     1     0     0     1     0
%    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     1
```

We can then sum across the columns to count the number of elements in `X` that were equal to a given value in `Y`.

```
sum(bsxfun(@eq, Y, X.'), 2)

%   1
%   3
%   2
```

On newer versions of MATLAB (since R2016b), you can omit the `bsxfun` since the equality operation will automatically broadcast.

```
sum(Y - X.', 2)
```

## A Memory-Efficient Option

The first option isn't the most efficient since it requires creating a matrix that is `[numel(Y), numel(X)]` elements large. Another way which may be more memory efficient may be to use the second output of `ismember` combined with accumarray

```
[tf, ind] = ismember(X, Y);
counts = accumarray(ind(tf), ones(sum(tf), 1), [numel(Y), 1], @numel);
```

**Explanation**

`ismember` is used to determine if the values in one array are in another. The first input tells us *if* each element of the first input is in the second input and the second output tells you *where* in the second input each element of the first input was found.

```
[tf, ind] = ismember(X, Y);

%   0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1
%   0 0 2 0 1 0 2 3 0 2 3
```

We can use the second input to "group" the same values together. The `accumarray` function does exactly this, it uses the `ind` variable above to determine groups and then applies a given operation to each group. In our case, we want to simply determine the number of element within each group. So to do that we can pass a second input the size of the `ind` input (minus the ones that didn't match) of ones, and then use `numel` as the operation (counts the number in each group)

```
counts = accumarray(ind(tf), ones(sum(tf), 1), [numel(Y), 1], @numel);

%   1
%   3
%   2
```

Comment: @Kristada673 How big are `X` and `Y`?

Comment: Pretty big. X has 5.88 million rows and Y has 1.1 million rows.

Comment: @Kristada673 Yikes! Try the second option that I just posted to see if that does better.

Comment: Wow! That worked! Could you kindly provide an explanation like you did in the first option?